# Webview inside a TabView crashes when showing a dialog screen

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a WebView in a TabView. The webView has a button. When the button is pressed a spinner is opened.
I am just loadng the webview with the URL. The action listener and spinner is triggered from the server side.

```
webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
....
....
webview.loadUrl(locationUrl);
```

My App is developed on Android 2.2. It is working fine in a device with OS 2.2 but crashing in 2.3.

Below is the log

```
11-24 13:44:24.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2684): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@406e21e0 is not valid; is your activity running?
11-24 13:44:24.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2684):     at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:527)
11-24 13:44:24.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2684):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
11-24 13:44:24.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2684):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
11-24 13:44:24.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2684):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
11-24 13:44:24.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2684):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
11-24 13:44:24.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2684):     at android.webkit.WebView$InvokeListBox.run(WebView.java:7583)
11-24 13:44:24.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2684):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-24 13:44:24.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2684):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-24 13:44:24.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2684):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-24 13:44:24.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2684):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-24 13:44:24.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2684):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-24 13:44:24.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2684):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-24 13:44:24.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2684):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-24 13:44:24.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2684):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-24 13:44:24.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2684):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Seems your context is out of scope. use getApplictionContext() to show dailog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use getparent() to get the parent context. As this is a tab, everything is done in parent context.